# Dividing a text file into 2 lists using python

Tags: python, list, ip, iteration

I have a text file which contains a list of IP addresses and Ports and it is organized as follows:

```
IP Port
```

for example:

```
212.212.212.212 80
111.111.111.111 8080
```

I have opened the file with python using the 'open' function and used readlines(), what I get is:

```
['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx\n','yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy yyy\n'...]
```

how can I divide this into 2 python lists which one will contain the IP's and the other will contain the Port's?

Thanks for the answers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use `split()`.

```
l=[]
y=[]
for x in f.readlines():
    l.append(x.split()[0])   #list of ip addresses
    y.append(x.split()[1])   #list of ports
```

EDIT:

```
x=['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx\n','yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy yyy\n']
l=[]

for i in x:
    l.append(i.split()[1])
print l
```

Comment: This gives me an empty list.. items did not append

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [generator-expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function.

```
data = ['212.212.212.212 80\n','111.111.111.111 8080\n']
result = zip(*((i.split()[0],i.split()[1]) for i in data))
print result[0], result[1]
```

Yields:

```
('212.212.212.212', '111.111.111.111') ('80', '8080')
```

Comment: got an error that data out of range for this attempt

Comment: How long is your list? `len(f.readlines())`. Can you include the traceback over here

Comment: The answer below is more simple for me. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ips = []
ports = []
f = file('datafile.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    ip,port = line.strip().split()
    ips.append(ip)
    ports.append(port)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `split()`

```
ipList = []
portList = []
F = open('inp.txt','r')
for line in F:
    ip, port = line.split()
    ipList.append(ip)
    portList.append(port)
```